# googletest testing framework c++: static method linker error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, testing, linker-errors, googletest

I'm trying to call static method from my TEST, but I'm getting unresolved external symbol.
What I've done so far:
Created 3 projects:

1. GoogleTest project as a static library - compiled gtest-all.cc and gtest_main.cc
2. MyProject - where I keep my .h and .cpp files
3. UnitTest project - where I keep tests

I've set up UnitTest's additional directories, lib directories, and referenced GoogleTest and MyProject. Tests run fine until I call static method from one of my classes...

**Linker options:**

```
/OUT:"D:\SkyDrive\Projekti\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\File System\Debug\Unit Test.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO "..\lib\part.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "D:\SkyDrive\Projekti\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\File System\Debug\Google Test.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug\Unit Test.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:\SkyDrive\Projekti\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\File System\Debug\Unit Test.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /PGD:"D:\SkyDrive\Projekti\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\File System\Debug\Unit Test.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

**Error:**

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static char __cdecl FS::mount(class Partition *)" (?mount@FS@@SADPAVPartition@@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Cluster_KernelFS_mountPartition_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@Cluster_KernelFS_mountPartition_Test@@EAEXXZ)   D:\SkyDrive\Projekti\Vi‌​sual Studio 2010\Projects\File System\Unit Test\cluster.obj
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to solve problem. At the very least you need to post the linker commandline from the failing build log and the linker's error messages. That might enable readers to guess the solution or to see what further information is needed.

Comment: @MikeKinghan linker message: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static char __cdecl FS::mount(class Partition *)" (?mount@FS@@SADPAVPartition@@@Z) referenced in function "private: virtual void __thiscall Cluster_KernelFS_mountPartition_Test::TestBody(void)" (?TestBody@Cluster_KernelFS_mountPartition_Test@@EAEXXZ) D:\SkyDrive\Projekti\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\File System\Unit Test\cluster.obj.

MyProject is using parition.lib static library.
Thanks for your reply

Comment: And what is the linker commandline?

Comment: @MikeKinghan ah yes, sry... here http://pastebin.com/EJEd9Fq8

Comment: Is `FS::mount(Partition *)` supposed to be defined in `part.lib`? If so where did you get this library? If not in what library is it defined?

Comment: FS::mount(Partition *) is defined in MyProject(Win32 console application). Partition is defined in part.lib. Calling partition methods in tests work fine.

Comment: So the problem static method is your own code in a class `FS`? What object file is supposed to contain the definition of `FS::mount` when it's compiled?

Comment: Yes, and fs.obj is supposed to.. FS::mount(...) is a wrapper method - it calls myImpl->mount(...) which is KernelFS class, and object file is kernelfs.obj

Comment: Well `fs.obj` and `kernelfs.obj` aren't linked by that link command.

Comment: Any ideas what should I do? I added reference to MyProject, and setup VC++ additional dirs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From our exchange of comments it looks clear that the linkage of your
googletest unit-test project (`Unit Test`) does not include necessary object files generated by the project that it is supposed to test (`MyProject`). `fs.obj` and
`kernelfs.obj` are at least two that are missing and from inspection of the
failing linker commandline it appears that you are linking *none* of the object files that 
implement the classes or functions you want to test (if there are any more)

You seem to believe that adding a Visual Studio project reference to `MyProject` to `Unit Test` will automatically provide the missing object file dependencies to `Unit Test`, but it won't.

The *quickest* way to remove the linkage errors would simply be to add the missing object files generated by `MyProject` to the `Unit Test`s project's **Configuration Properties** -> **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Dependencies**.

You could add each of the missing `.obj` files by a fully-qualified pathname that locates
it in the `Debug` output directory of `MyProject`. Or more easily, you could add the path to that  `Debug` directory to **Configuration Properties** -> **Linker** -> **Input** -> **Additional Directories**, and then simply add the unqualified name of the missing `.obj` file to **Additional Dependencies**.

But this would be a flawed solution because of course you want `Unit Test` always to
build on the latest source version of `MyProject` and not just whatever `MyProject` object
files happen to exist at the time. In that case you have two options:-

- a) You can add the *source files* that generate the missing `.obj` files to the `Unit Test` project as well as `MyProject`. In `Unit Test`'s **Solution Explorer** view, right-click **Source Files** and navigate **Add** -> **Existing Item**. In this case you must take care that whenever your add a new source file to `MyProject` you also add it to `Unit Test`.
- b) This option assumes that both projects are in the same solution. If they're not you
  can make them so. Then you can, first, carry out the quick-but-flawed solution (and test it).  Then to fix the flaw, you can make `Unit Test` *dependent* on `MyProject`, so that whenever you build `Unit Test`, `MyProject` will automatically be built first if it is out-of-date. To create this dependency, right-click `Unit Test` in the **Solution Explorer** pane, navigate **Build Dependencies** -> **Project Dependencies** -> **Dependencies** and tick the checkbox to make `Unit Test` depend on `MyProject`. In this case you must take care that whenever a new `.obj` file is to be generated by `MyProject` you add it to the additional linker dependencies of `Unit Test`.

(b) Is the better practice.

All of the above assumes that you have correctly configured `Unit Test` so that the compiler searches the include-directories of `MyProject` and correctly locates its header files. You don't seem to have any build errors on that score.

**Follow up Q. 1**

> Could you explain to me why doesn't the linker link any object files from MyProject (and I have to add them manually).

As far as the Visual Studio is concerned, `MyProject` and `Unit Test` are just two projects
contained in the same solution that build different executables. It doesn't "know" that the purpose  of `Unit Test` is to unit-test `MyProject` and therefore will need to link all of the object files  generated by `MyProject` that contain functionality that `Unit Test` is going to test. So why *would* it automatically add `MyProject`'s object files to `Unit Test`'s linkage?

Even if Visual Studio did somehow know that the purpose of `Unit Test` was to unit-test `MyProject`, how would it know *which* of `MyProject`'s object files it should link in `Unit Test`? One of them might contain a `main()` function - which will in fact be the case if `MyProject` builds a console application - but `Unit Test` also generates a `main()` function in one of its object files; so linking *all* the `MyProject` object files in `Unit Test` would be impossible: it would cause a `multiply defined symbol` error.

I pointed out that giving `Unit Test` a project reference to `My Project` does not have the effect of adding all `My Project`'s object files to `Unit Test`'s linkage. You now see one
reason why it couldn't have that effect.

And that reason exemplifies a more general one: When you link object files to build an executable, it's a linkage error for the same symbol to be visible in multiple object files. Which one is supposed to get linked? But of course it's not any kind of error for the same symbol to be visible in the linkages of *different* executables. That means you can't simply scoop up a bunch of object files from the linkage of one executable and add them to the linkage of another executable and expect it to work. If you want to add object files from one executable to the linkage of another, you have to know that some such mixture *can* be linked and what mixture you want. You have to know which  symbols are meant to be linked from which object files to make the second executable and select the
object files accordingly. As you say, it's a "manual" exercise.

Visual Studio's Project Reference feature would help you if `MyProject` generated a *library* rather than an executable. In that case creating a reference from `Unit Test` to `MyProject` would (among other things) tell Visual Studio that by default the `MyProject` library will be added to the linkage of `Unit Test`. Libraries, unlike plain object files, are created *for the purpose* of being being linked with different executables, so it's natural for the MS Project Reference feature to support automation of library dependencies. It's also natural to assume that if a project generates an executable, not a library, then its object files are just a by-product and not intended to be linked with other executables.

The text-book way of organizing your work would be in *three* projects:-

- `MyLib`, generating  library that contains all the functionality you want to unit-test.
- `MyProject`, generating the same executable as at present, but linking `MyLib`
- `Unit Test`, generating an executable that unit-tests `MyLib`, also linking `MyLib`

**Follow up Q. 2**

> Explain to me how to configure the linker to link .objs from MyProject's debug folder?

I already have. Paragraph 4, "Or more easily..." etc. There is no way you can avoid having
to specify the individual `.obj` files to be linked. You can't instruct the linker "Just link whatever object files you find in `/path/to/MyProject/Debug`", because for the reasons I've explained, the linker doesn't do things as sloppy as that.

Comment: Worked like a charm, but could you explain me why doesn't linker link any object files from MyProject (and I have to add them manually), and maybe if it isn't too hard, explain me how to configure linker to link .objs from MyProject's debug folder?