# main doesn't call the test sources of gtest

Tags: c++, eclipse, googletest

I am trying to run tests of google test I've written for my program.
but the main doesn't call those source files.

any ideas?

this is my main:

```
#include "gtest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "System.h"

GTEST_API_ int main(int argc, char **argv){

    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    //System s;
}
```

this is one of my tests:

```
#include "gtest.h"
#include "Movie.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

Movie *firstMovie = new Movie("03205", "The Great Movie", "one of the best movies ever",
                        8.9, 1995, 125);
Movie *secondMovie = new Movie("0245", "new Movie", "an ok movie", 7, 2001, 135);
Movie *thirdMovie = new Movie("02451", "new Movie2", "a good movie", 3, 2022, 79);

/*
 * this function checks the unity of the names.
 */
TEST(TestMovie1,checkNames) {

    cout<<firstMovie->GetName();
    cout<<secondMovie->GetName();
    cout<<thirdMovie->GetName();

    EXPECT_NE(firstMovie->GetName(), secondMovie->GetName());
    EXPECT_NE(firstMovie->GetName(), thirdMovie->GetName());
    EXPECT_NE(thirdMovie->GetName(), secondMovie->GetName());
}
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you link your test cpp file with your main?

Comment: What command did you use to compile your code?

Comment: what do you mean? in an early exercise the google test ran. my program is compiled with g++ (through ecplise). my program without google test is working fine, with arguments from the console.

Comment: You need two different compilation projects: one for your application and another one for the tests. Looks like your application's `main` is overriding the so-called gtest `main`. Could be?

Comment: This seems really similar to a question [I just answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34190101/139855) about the relationship between production code and test code when unit testing with google test.

Comment: I found my mistake. I had a while loop that waited for console, and I didn't have a console on the gtest.